Preloading nested Rails associations with a condition without updating models
To provide a simple example, let's say I want to load ALL hospitals for an organization and preload ONLY the doctors that have a calendar, but at the same time, I do not want to create any scopes or additional associations in the models, so the models should remain the same. How would I do that?
With some pseudo code, I want something along the lines of:
def find_facilities(organization)
  doctors_query = Doctor.joins(:calendar).includes(:calendar)

  organization.facilities.preload(doctors: doctors_query)
end

It's also important that not only do I want to check that the calendar exists, I also want to preload it.
And another point is that the calendar has a foreign key to the doctors, not the other way around.

Unfortunately I don't believe you can do this with preloading or eager loading. Your current requirement is: Facilities with no Doctors, Facilities with Doctors without Calendars (but don't load the doctors or calendars), Facilities with Doctors with Calendars (load Doctors and Calendars). Generally speaking we could do this with a multi conditional join however when using eager loading the join is applied by rails and we cannot manipulate it, without an extraordinary amount of effort that would likely be extremely fragile....

...Using preload we could apply conditions to the second query but this would require adding an association, which for some reason is off the table. At this point I can manage to get #1 and #3 but you will lose the facilities from #2.

Why is it that the models cannot be changed? That makes it a very difficult nut to crack.

I am surprised that it's hard considering that preload will issue a separate query for each association anyway, so being able to modify it seems like something that should be trivial. And I don't want to modify the models because I will have a lot of queries like that and I don't want to pollute my models with scopes and associations for each possible scenario

@NoDisplayName why not just preload everything and then subsequently filter for display purposes? i.e. organization.facilities.preload(doctors: :calendar) and then use conditionals doctor.calendar ? do_something : do_nothing?

@NoDisplayName eager_load and preload give you almost zero control over the actual query and limiting has_many assocations is much more difficult than you would think. I can kind of appreachiate not wanting to bloat the model but one the only feasible solutions here is to define assocations with a scope applied and unless you want to be using class eval to define those from the outside (don't) then you're making things much more difficult on yourself with this restriction.
